# How do I obtain Excel objects for using as C#4 dynamic interop method call arguments?

Tags: c#, excel, dynamic, office-interop

I have a great time interop'ing with excel. It's a breeze... until I hit a brick wall.

This works like a charm.

```
dynamic excel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

which allows stuff like

```
var headercell = excel.Cells(RowNumber,ColumnNumber);
headercell.Value = moddef.Name;
headercell.Orientation = -60;
headercell.Font.Color = 0x00AA00;
headercell.Interior.Color =0xCCCCCC;
headercell.Font.Size = 20;      
headercell.ClearComments();
headercell.Data = "Here we are LIVE with excel";
```

This is all nice and well because I thus far am only using simple types interacting with excel. However, I want to draw a border around a table.

```
var bottomright = headercell.Offset(height,width);  
var wholeSection = excel.Range(headercell,bottomright);
wholeSection.BorderAround(/*what goes in here??*/);
```

in the msdn article [Range object members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225606.aspx) the [BorderAround](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209714.aspx) method displays some arguments to be passed in. Thus far, I have not had to reference the Excel interop assemblies. Do I have to reference it in order to create the BorderAround arguments or is there another general trick to how I should approach invoking methods requiring Excel type arguments?

Comment: Three of the arguments you have to pass are enums.  You can continue on without the interop assembly but that requires looking up the integral values.  They are not readily documented, it is just a whole lot simpler to add the reference.

Comment: I am still discovering the power of COM object affinity in C#4, I see. I didn't know that I could cast the obtained COM object to Interop.Excel.Application object. I thought that the signatures would be incompatible. Now it's even easier, and with intellisense.